# How to manage click on marker which is not in Cluster in Android Google Map API?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am having trouble implementing OnClickListener for Marker(s) which are not in Cluster, i.e. not added using:

```
 mClusterManager.addItem(markerCluster);
```

I have set OnMarkerClickLister as follows:

```
 mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
```

If I just use:

```
 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

the click on markers is not working at all.

For example: I have this situation:

[image]

Two green dots and big blue dot (with number 6) are one Cluster, but the red marker is not in Cluster as I don't want it to be Clustered like other markers.
InfoWindow is normally showing when I click on red marker, but onMarkerClick doesn't work - as well as OnClusterItemClickListener. But OnClusterItemClickListener works when I click on markers which are in Cluster.

Hope you understand what I am trying to achieve. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Can I add all Markers to Cluster and exclude them from Clustering? Or what is the solution here?

Comment: I guess the listener on marker should be independent of clusterManager

Comment: why don't you just pass the context?

Comment: For Activity
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
For Fragment
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(getActivity());

Comment: try and tell me if it works

Comment: I am getting this error for Fragment:
cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$OnMarkerClickListener. I used this, what Android Studio ask for:  mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener((GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) getContext());

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Updated answer**

The image that you added in your edit explains the issue clearly, thanks for that!

In order too solve this issue we need to register the listener differently. Namely: by registering it to the ClusterManager's MarkerManager as that class handles everything of the markers now. We also need to add the NormalMarkers a bit differently, so lets go through it step by step:

1) Update the `OnMarkerClickListener` of the `mMap`:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager.getMarkerManager()); // Note the `MarkerManager` here
```

2) This `MarkerManager` holds all the collections. We need to create a new collection on this manager to which we will add the NormalMarkers that should be displayed apart from the clusters:

```
MarkerManager.Collection normalMarkersCollection = mClusterManager.getMarkerManager().newCollection();
```

3) Adding the markers is done similar to how this was before, but with using the `addMarker()` method on the collection that we created. We must pass a `MarkerOptions()` object to this:

```
// Create a normal marker
val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(...))
    .title("My marker")
    .snippet("With description")

// Add it to the collection
normalMarkersCollection.addMarker(markerOptions)
```

4) Last but not least: we want the `OnClickListener` on it:

```
normalMarkersCollection.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {
    public boolean onMarkerClick(marker: Marker) {
        // NORMAL MARKER CLICKED!
        return false;
    }
})
```

5) Done! Now the normal markers are added to the map just like before, but with a working `OnMarkerClickListener`.

---

**Earlier answer**

*(Setting the click listeners for the clusters and clustered items)*

You should add the clicklistener to the `mClusterManager`. Setting the clicklistener on the `mMap` does not work when using the ClusterManager.

Thus instead of using `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener`, set the `ClusterItemClickListener` on the cluster manager:

```
mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MyItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(MyItem item) {
        Log.d("cluster item","clicked");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Additionally, if you want to capture the onclick of the clustered item item, use the `ClusterClickListener`:

```
mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MyItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
        Log.d("cluster","clicked");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I understand that, but I could have one or more markers which are not in Cluster - I don't want them to be Clustered like the rest of markers. How to listen for their click events?

Comment: I see now, your updated question describes the issue clearly with the image. Check out my updated answer to solve this :)

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I have added Listener like you said, but instead of _mClusterManager.markerManager.newCollection()_ I used _normalMarkersCollection = mClusterManager.getMarkerManager().newCollection()_ because first is not working for me. Later, I've tried to use  _normalMarkersCollection.addMarker()_, but it's asking me to add **MarkerOptions** - I can't add just Marker I created. And when I do, Click Listener for normal marker is still not working.

Comment: Ah true, using `mClusterManager.markerManager` will only work in Kotlin (which is what I use). For Java we must use the `getMarkerManager()` yeah. I will update it in the answer.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot the `MarkerOptions` that we need for this, it basically contains all the data of the NormalMarker, but wrapped in another object. Just add the NormalMarkers like this: `normalMarkersCollection.addMarker( MarkerOptions().postition(new LatLng(...).title("Normal marker").snipper("Description")) )`. I will update my answer to describe this too

Comment: Thank you so much! Now is everything finally working. Hope it will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have both Marker and Cluster listeners working you can write

```
mGoogleMap.getMarkerManager().onMarkerClick(marker);
```

inside your `OnMarkerClickListener`