# How to make separate marker click listener between normal marker and cluster marker in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have some normal marker as well as cluster marker. googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager) listener override to normal marker listener and normal marker click not working. So, i want to handle both marker click separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution From [How to manage click on marker which is not in Cluster in Android Google Map API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52204424/how-to-manage-click-on-marker-which-is-not-in-cluster-in-android-google-map-api?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

**For Normal Marker**

1. `googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager.getMarkerManager());`
2. `MarkerManager.Collection normalMarkersCollection = mClusterManager.getMarkerManager().newCollection();`
3. **Create a normal marker**

   `MarkerOptions markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
       .position(new LatLng(...))
       .title("Title")
       .snippet("Description")`

Add Normal marker into "normalMarkersCollection"

```
normalMarkersCollection.addMarker(markerOptions)
```

4. **Set click for normal marker.**

   `normalMarkersCollection.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {
       public boolean onMarkerClick(marker: Marker) {
           // NORMAL MARKER CLICKED!
           return false;
       }
   });`

**For Cluster Marker**

```
mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<ClusterItemClass>(){
  @Override
    public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<ClusterItemClass> cluster) {
      //logic for handle on cluster click
    }
});

mClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<ClusterItemClass>(){
  @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(ClusterItemClass item) {
      //logic for handle on cluster item click
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`ClusterManager` have separate methods for this:

`setOnClusterItemClickListener` handles on `Marker` click

`setOnClusterClickListener` handles on `Cluster` click

Both `Marker` and `Cluster` are markers on map. You specify that your `ClusterManager` will manage on markers clicks via `googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager)`.

And now you need to set `setOnClusterItemClickListener` and `setOnClusterClickListener` for `ClusterManager`

**Sample**

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager)
mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<ClusterItemClass>(){
  @Override
    public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<ClusterItemClass> cluster) {
      //logic for handle on cluster click
    }
});
mClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<ClusterItemClass>(){
  @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(ClusterItemClass item) {
      //logic for handle on cluster item click
    }
});
```

Checkout more in [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering)

Comment: When i set "map.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager)" then normal marker click not working but cluster working and if i set "googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);" then normal marker click working but cluster not working.

Comment: Normal marker click listener not working after i set "googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager)".

Comment: You not need to set again ```setOnMarkerClickListener``` to map. When you call ```googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager)``` on markers click event will handle your ```ClusterManager```. On normal marker click you should handle in ```setOnClusterItemClickListener``` method of your ```mClusterManager```

Comment: I already checked that case but normal marker click is not working. Normal marker click override by cluster marker when i set "googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager)". Normal marker not available in cluster so, thats marker clicks not working.

Comment: Checkout documentation

Comment: "normal marker click" cannot work, because that event handles ```ClusterManager```. You specify it by this line of code: ```googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager)```